# ccTouch event on all same sprite ( sprite array )

Tags: iphone, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone, touch

I have just started learning Cocos2d from one tutorial. I want to fly 'Bats' randomly and when i touch anywhere on screen all Bats gathered at my touch position and them again start fly randomly.
Here is my code :

```
-(id) init
{
if( (self=[super init])) {

    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"Bat.plist"];

    //Bats Array Initialization
    bats = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //Add bats using a batch node.
    CCSpriteBatchNode *batch1 = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"Bat.png" capacity:10];
    [self addChild:batch1 z:2 tag:TAG_BATS];

    //Make them start flying up.
    for(int x=0; x<5; x++){
        //Create SimpleAnimObject of bat
        bat1 = [SimpleAnimObj spriteWithBatchNode:batch1 rect:CGRectMake(0,0,48,48)];
        [batch1 addChild:bat1];
        [bat1 setPosition:ccp(arc4random()%900+40, arc4random()%600+50)];
        [bat1 setScale:0.6f];

        float flappingSpeed = [self makeBatFlyUp:bat1];
        bat1.velocity = ccp((arc4random()%1000)/500 + 0.2f, 0.1f/flappingSpeed);

        [bats addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:bat1]];
        [bat1 retain];

        //Set the bat's direction based on x velocity.
        if(bat1.velocity.x > 0){
            bat1.flipX = YES;
        }
    }

    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
    [self schedule:@selector(step:)];


}
return self;
}
-(float)makeBatFlyUp:(SimpleAnimObj*)bat {
CCSpriteFrameCache * cache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];

float delay = (float)(arc4random()%5+5)/150;
CCAnimation *animation = [[CCAnimation alloc] initWithName:@"simply_bat_fly" delay:delay];

int num = arc4random()%9+1;
for(int i=1; i<=9; i+=1){
    [animation addFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"b%i.tiff",num]]];
    num++;
    if(num > 9){ num = 1; }
}       

[bat stopAllActions];
[bat runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation]]];

bat.animationType = BAT_FLYING_UP;

return delay;
}
```

In touch event :

```
-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];
touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];

float velocityBat =  1024/3.0 ;

CGPoint moveDifference = ccpSub(touchLocation,bat1.position );
float distanceMove = ccpLength(moveDifference);
float moveduration = distanceMove /   velocityBat;

// here i have to use Array but i don't know how to use array to access all same sprites.

self.moveAction = [CCSequence actions:                          
                   [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:moveduration position:touchLocation],
                   [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(bearMoveEnded)],
                   nil
                   ];
[bat1 runAction:moveAction];

return YES;
}
```

Bats are flying properly but when i touch on screen only one Bat follow my touch event others are keep moving randomly.
Can any one help me here? If i miss any thing or where i am wrong ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one reference to a bat that you're using: the `bat1` variable. You need to use the bats array to access all of the bats.

Also, get rid of the `[bat1 retain]` line because by adding each bat to the bats array it is already retained. Cocos nodes are also retained when you make them a child of a parent by calling `addChild:node`.

Comment: I see.. First thanks buddy..!! Can you please give me some idea - 'How can i use the `bats` array to access all bats?' Any sample code or hint can be great help !!

Comment: You need to know which bat you want to address. Then get that bat via [bats objectAtIndex:0] (this would return the first bat).

Comment: But I want all bats (all bats are on random position )to follow my touch location. I am totally new to Cocos2d so i really don't know that- Is it possible or not ? and If yes then can you please guide li'l more on coding side?